New tenant b2clogin URL returns error with "removed or changed"
I recently set up a new tenant to match an existing one.
When I do
wget https://myoldtenant.b2clogin.com/tfp/myoldtenantm/b2c_1a_signin/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

I get a 200 response.
When I replace myoldtenant with mynewtenant, I get an error indicating "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable"
I am 'certain' (famous last words) the tenant exists and has the correct name.  Is there a separate step that I am missing to enable the tenant or some such?  I don't know how to validate my URL.
Any suggestions?

Compare the configurations between the old and new tenants to identify any discrepancies and Check that the policy (b2c_1a_signin in your case) exists in the new tenant

In my old b2c tenant, when I used the below endpoint, I got result successfully:
https://infrab2c.b2clogin.com/infrab2c.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration


The error "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable" usually occurs if the tenant's name you are passing is invalid or if the user flow policy does not exist in the new B2C tenant.
I got the same error when tried with new B2C tenant:
https://rukk33.b2clogin.com/rukk33.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_testruk/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration


When checked in the new B2C tenant, the user does not exist:

Hence to resolve the issue make sure the user flow policy exists in the new tenant or create the new user flow:

Now I am able to get the results in the new B2C tenant:

If still the issue persists, verify the tenant's name or create the new tenant and recheck.

Thanks Rukmini.  It turns out my policy name was incorrect for the new tenant.  My old tenant is using b2c_1a_signin.  But the new tenant is using b2c_1_signin.  I missed this detail.  Thanks for pushing me to double check everything.
